# Unexpected interfaces in ifconfig

Tags: network

In the middle of installing a tool called mrtg, I bailed out from a perl script to set various configuration parameters for use of snmp because it became clear that I had no idea what I was doing.  I also explored some snmp commands myself, but didn't keep a record, unfortunately.

I come back to ifconfig and notice it shows three new interfaces (not there just before the previous adventure):

```
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
fw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 4078
    lladdr 60:fb:42:ff:fe:f4:cd:9e 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
```

My laptop on the same LAN has a different new interface called p2p0 that I hadn't noticed before, as well as gif0 and stf0 but not fw0.

After I reset my Airport Extreme to factory default, and reinstalled OS X Lion on my machine, with a wiped disk, they are still there.  This:

```
sudo ifconfig gif0 destroy
```

makes gif0 go away, but on reboot it comes back.  There is a previous [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16189/what-applications-would-be-expected-to-setup-a-network-interface-stf0-and-gif) with some info but what I'd like to know is why are they still there despite a clean install, could they be a security risk, and should I or can I make them go away.  Should I be looking at the Airport or something in my StartupItems?

UPDATE:  Does my machine set these up at boot or does the Airport remember them?  And in either case, why didn't a clean install (or factory reset) restore them to the previous configuration?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`fw0` is the FireWire network interface. It's benign.

`stf0` is an IPv6 to IPv4 tunnel interface. It's a bridge connection that exists to help us transition from IPv4 to the IPv6 standard. It's benign. You can read more about it here if you like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4

`gif0` is a generic tunnel interface. It's used to tunnel IPv4 traffic to an IPv6 network and back. It's benign. You can read more about it here: http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=4&topic=gif

Comment: As to why the interfaces appeared, my best guess is that while they showed up after the snmp adventure, they weren't caused by it.  FWIW, fiddling with Network Prefs does not change output of a plain ifconfig (including deleting FireWire as shown in the answer.  A change to the IPv6 configuration in Network Prefs is reversed by a reboot.

Comment: I have a `p2p0`. Any explanations?

Comment: If it has an IPv6 address in the block fe80::/64 it's a local link interface.

Answer (score 7):

p2p0 is AirDrop, according to https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4784003

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This is not right. No airdrop traffic goes over p2p0 but instead awdl0

Answer (score 3):

The gif0 is a generic virtual interface, stf0 is an ipv6 interface and fw0 is your firewire interface. You shouldn't worry about these.

Answer (score -1):

p2p0 interface belong to VirtualBox, after you installed VB into my Mac, you will get this interface.

Comment: I have never installed VirtualBox but I have this interface in my Macbook Pro.

Comment: According to https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4784003 p2p0 is AirDrop, not VirtualBox