# What are the different internet connection types used by ifconfig and ipconfig?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, system-information

Typing `ifconfig` on the command line gives me listings for several devices. I've seen at least the following ones:

- `lo0`
- `gif0`
- `stf0`
- `en0`
- `en1`
- `en2`
- `en3`
- `p2p0`
- `awdl0`
- `bridge0`

What specifically do each of them refer to? I know `en0` is a wireless connection, `en3` is a connection using a Thunderbolt-to-ethernet adapter, and `en1` is an ordinary ethernet connection. What about the rest?

Comment: If your first discovered network interface is WiFi, en0 would be wireless, but Macs with physical wired Ethernet have en0 as wired in most cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are properly known as BSD names, so you can look at the BSD / Darwin source code to see what these mean.

- `en` is Ethernet
- `lo` is loop back or local host
- `awdl` is air drop peer to peer (a type of mesh network)
- `bridge` is a [connection between networks](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/network-bridging.html)
- `p2p` is sometimes a virtualization link and also some people have reported it being used with AirDrop before that changed to be `awdl0`

The numbers added to the end just increment as you add a second interface of the same type. The rest are tunneling interfaces for VPN and bridging between IPv4 and IPv6:

- [see Ian's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/47481/5472) on question [Unexpected interfaces in ifconfig](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47477/unexpected-interfaces-in-ifconfig)

Comment: Not all `en` refer to a wired ethernet connection. Are wireless connections considered a form of ethernet? (If so, how?)

Comment: @jvriesem The media section will let you know if an Ethernet connection uses wired connections in most cases (and which flavor)  - the `en` tag commingles both wired and wireless hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The -v flag provides a type info on some interfaces, for example *IP over Thunderbolt* for `en2`:

```
ifconfig -v en2                              
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 6
    eflags=41000080<TXSTART,ECN_ENABLE,FASTLN_ON>
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:02:9f:a3:0c:00 
    netif: EF77BC13-3B69-466C-8BA2-591CCA2D6C44
    flowswitch: C155EE61-3E2C-465E-9AFB-17C36ECD8F8C
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
    type: IP over Thunderbolt
    agent domain:Skywalk type:NetIf flags:0xa443 desc:"Userspace Networking"
    agent domain:Skywalk type:FlowSwitch flags:0x4403 desc:"Userspace Networking"
    state availability: 0 (true)
    scheduler: FQ_CODEL 
    qosmarking enabled: yes mode: none
    low power mode: disabled
    multi layer packet logging (mpklog): disabled
    routermode4: disabled
    routermode6: disabled
```