# What is the network interface anpi?

Tags: network

For context, I am working on a 2023 MBP with M3 Pro.

When I type `ifconfig` into the terminal, I get a variety of network interfaces, all of which I've been able to find some pretty thorough documentation on except for one called `anpi0`. The only reference I could find for what this might be was [Platforms and Software Systems for an Autonomic Internet](https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/laurent.lefevre/pdf/GLOBECOM2010.pdf) , which suggests it might stand for Autonomic Network Programming Interface. This seems reasonable, but this paper is from 2010 and if it is what this is referring to, I am a little taken aback that it was as hard as it was to find this info, and there are only 10-year-old papers from somewhat obscure conferences that I can find to talk about them. I can't seem to find anything recent discussing them.

I did some of the things mentioned in the answer [How do I delete network interfaces](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281277/how-do-i-delete-network-interfaces) to try to find the piece of hardware connected to this network interface with no luck, suggesting that maybe it is a virtual network interface. I also noticed that this interface was not present in this person's output for `ifconfig`.

So what is `anpi`? What is its role in Macs today, and what kind of situations activate it?

Comment: Being the curious type with a little time... According to this post https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-python-chooses-mac-address-uuidv1-chaim-sanders "...a virtual USB-C Dual Role Device (DRD) with a locally administered MAC address." *Exactly* what that means is unclear to me. Perhaps that will help you?

Comment: Your discovery re Autonomic Network Programming Interface may well be on the spot.  Wish I could find something to tie this into my answer (exploration) below or that from @JBRWilkinson.

Answer (score 3):

Typing the following command line:

`ifconfig -v anpi0`

gives output which includes these elements:

```
ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
type: USB Ethernet
agent domain:Skywalk type:NetIf flags:0xa443 desc:"Userspace Networking"
```

`defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist`

lists Network Interfaces. For me, `anpi0` corresponded to this block:

```
"BSD Name" = anpi0;
            HiddenConfiguration = 1;
            HiddenInterface = 1;
            IOBuiltin = 0;
            IOInterfaceNamePrefix = anpi;
            IOInterfaceType = 6;
            IOInterfaceUnit = 0;
            IOMACAddress = {length = 6, bytes = 0xaabbccddeeff};
            IOPathMatch = "IOService:/AppleARMPE/arm-io@xxxx/AppleT810xIO/usb-drd0@xxxx/AppleT8103USBXDCI@0/AppleUSBNCMDataAux@3/AppleUSBDeviceNCMData/anpi0";
            SCNetworkInterfaceInfo =             {
                UserDefinedName = "Ethernet Adapter (anpi0)";
            };
            SCNetworkInterfaceType = Ethernet;
        },
```

> Note the `HiddenInterface = 1`

..so some USB device uses this Network Interface, but perhaps not until plugged in.

I plugged in a USB-to-Network adapter I had but this did not change anything, nor did plugging in an iPhone over Lightning-USB.

Digging further:

```
ioreg -l | grep anpi 
    | |   |       +-o anpi0  <class AppleUSBDeviceNCMPrivateEthernetInterface, id 0x100000740, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 11>
    | |   |         |   "BSD Name" = "anpi0"
    | |   |         |   "IOInterfaceNamePrefix" = "anpi"
```

Web Search for 'Apple NCM Private Interface' yields [this Mastodon post](https://mastodon.social/@_inside/111597639613328413) which says that `anpi0` and `anpi1` could be the debugging interfaces for XCode. I've recently uninstalled XCode but the interfaces persist on my M1 MacMini.

From all my research, my summary would be **ignore it**; it's an *inactive* network interface likely used to bridge user-mode networking (like in a device simulator) across to real networking.

Comment: Could also run `sudo ifconfig anpi0 down` and see if anything breaks.

Comment: I have also done an "answer". Just an exploration which I hope you find complementary to yours.

Answer (score 2):

My exloration starts by duplicating the beginning of the answer from @JBRWilkinson.

Typing the following command line:

`ifconfig -v anpi0`

gives output which includes this element:

```
    agent domain:Skywalk type:NetIf flags:0xa443 desc:"Userspace Networking"
```

From the `domain:Skywalk`, I deduce it is part of the Skywalk subsystem.

Now do `sudo skywalkctl list-providers | grep anp` which confirms this:

```
net-if com.apple.netif.anpi1 075863F8-8544-40DE-A080-CB796BCA01DC
net-if com.apple.netif.anpi0 68CCB46E-D64B-49DC-A017-EFCBDDCF4981
```

The full listing shows that non-physical interfaces like en1, en2, en3 are also associated with Skywalk.

So the real question is perhaps: What is Skywalk and the role of its many interfaces?

AFAIK, this is undocumented by Apple and the details are not included in any listing of the XNU kernel.

What can we find:

`man skywalkctl` does not get us much further - it includes:

```
skywalkctl is a utility used to interact with the Skywalk subsystem, which provides the plumbing between various
       networking-related pieces of software and hardware.  It should only be used in a test and debug context. Using it
       for any other purpose is strongly discouraged.
```

`skywalkctl` has various sub-commands which I feel I am not equipped to explore. Can someone else expand on this?

The command `skywalkctl tree` lists all the devices associated with Skywalk. Note, this subcommand is not in the man page!

The only reference I can find of any authority is near the end of this [bonus chapter of *OS Internals](https://newosxbook.com/bonus/vol1ch16.html) book by Jonathan Levin.

I hesitate to call this an answer, it is really an exploration.

Comment: Thanks for the followup! `skywalkctl status` tells me it is not enabled, further evidence to ignore it.