How to determine if there is a stealth proxy server recording my computer?
Sorry for rough question, I'm not an engineeer.
My company just bought me an Apple computer. I've heard of privacy leaks and computer data stealers such as proxy server, etc.
I know firewall proxy server can record all your internet data coming out of computers.
I was wondering if there are any stats to find out proxies in terminal even if they have been hidden by design or implementation.
I tried ifconfig in my computer.
here are some proxies among them.
lo0 gif0 anpi1 en2 bridge0 ap1 vmenet0
Are these an indicator of potential security or privacy compromises?

If the computer was issued to you by your employer, it's their property and they can do as they see fit with it. You should have no expectation of privacy while using it, and you should not use it for any personal business. That said, you can check for a proxy configuration in System Settings > Network > Wi-Fi or Ethernet > Details > Proxies. No matter what you see there, if they want to monitor you without your knowledge, they can.

Are you concerned about company operated proxy services, or non-company interception of traffic? Does the company have an IT department or someone responsible for the computer's set up?

@GrahamMiln yeah, IT department has an server room recording our computers. I want to check my computer. Just to make sure the spying strats my company is using even when i'm home.

lo0 gif0 anpi1 en2 bridge0 ap1 vmenet0 are not proxies, they are network devices, physical and virtual. Most are standard macOS, and some may be installed by other software.

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/467852/what-is-the-network-interface-anpi and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16189/what-applications-would-be-expected-to-setup-a-network-interface-stf0-and-gif?rq=1

Proxies are not the only way to record network traffic. Network Extensions are software on your Mac which can intercept/record/modify network traffic.

Much will depend on your legal jurisdiction. As broad advice:

Assume work devices are monitored;
Do not assume privacy of any activity performed on a work device;
Do not connect personal devices to a work network;
Do not perform any private or personal task on a work device.

It should be the responsibility of your company's IT staff to keep your device secure. Talk to them about any concerns you have.
Proxies on macOS
Concerning proxies and Internet traffic, as @Linc D. comments, macOS's proxy settings are visible at:

System Settings > Network > Wi-Fi or Ethernet > Details > Proxies

For a command line interface, see the networksetup tool.
VPNs and Transparent Proxies
If work requires the use of a Virtual Private Network (VPN), your traffic passes through work's network and can be monitored.
For "hidden" proxy servers, these are called transparent proxies and are network specific and can not be trivially detected:

Also known as an intercepting proxy, inline proxy, or forced proxy, a transparent proxy intercepts normal application layer communication without requiring any special client configuration. Clients need not be aware of the existence of the proxy. A transparent proxy is normally located between the client and the Internet, with the proxy performing some of the functions of a gateway or router.

See see How can I find out if there is a proxy between myself and the Internet if there are no proxy setting specified in the browser?

thx, I have a picture now. So the only way to find out transparent proxies is to simply build a cheap (arm,docker) server on my own. Use the computer to connect to it and check the IP address is the same or not. Beacause IP address changed when proxies are set in the middle.
